# Android 4.4.4 can not connect to Nordic semi SDK 13 devices

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I use the NRF-toolbox app's UART feature for connecting to Nordic-semiconductor based devices.
Android version is 4.4.4 and the device used is a Samsung device.
Everything was working fine when nordic device was using SDK 11, Softdevice S132 v3.
But after migration to SDK 13 and softdevice S132 v4.0.2, connection does not go through.
The connect request succeeds, but service discovery fails with GAT_INTERNAL_ERROR (0x81).
This is followed by a disconnection of the device (GATT_ERROR 0x85).
Same behaviour is seen through NRF-connect as well.

Is support for 4.4.4 android dropped from SDK 13, softdevice S132v4.0.2? I have searched nordic documentation but have not found anything related to my problem.

**Update:**
In SDK 13, a "GATT module" was introduced and is enabled by default. This was the reason for the problem. For more details - check the thread on https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/136600/can-not-connect-to-devices-with-sdk-13-from-android-444/

Answer (score 0):

In SDK 13, a "GATT module" was introduced and is enabled by default. This was the reason for the problem. For more details - check the thread on https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/136600/can-not-connect-to-devices-with-sdk-13-from-android-444/